# Running a cron job in Symfony2 - trying to call a method in a controller

Tags: php, symfony, cron

I'm having a nightmare trying to set up a cron job in my Symfony2 project.

I understand the principle of setting it up and where to put the code but I just cannot get it to do what I need.

Basically, I need the cron job to run every day and check a database of clients in order to find out if an invoice needs sending. The actual client referencing is yet to be done but I have written a test which I want to generate and email and invoice based on hardcoded values I pass to the function.

```
// AppBundle/Command/CronRunCommand.php

protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {

        $request = new Request();
        $request->attributes->set('client','14');
        $request->attributes->set('invoice_id','3');
        $request->attributes->set('dl','0');

        $output->writeln('<comment>Running Invoice Cron Task...</comment>');

        return $this->getContainer()->get('invoices')->generateInvoiceAction($request);

    }
```

I have set invoices up as a service in my config.yml:

```
services:
  invoices:
      class: AppBundle\Controller\InvoiceController
```

And in InvoiceController there is a function that will generate an invoice by using Invoice Painter Bundle and then send it to the specified email address (currently hard coded for development purposes).

When I run the cron command on my console, it throws the following error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  
  Error: Call to a member function has() on null
```

I have searched for this and I believe it is to do with the fact that it's referencing a controller method and my command file does not extend controller, but I'm so confused about how I can do this - surely there is a way of running a method in a controller as a cron job?

Any help appreciated.

Michael

Comment: While calling a controller from a console app can be done it is not recommended.  Instead, move your invoice functionality to it's own service and then call the service from your console app.  And of course change your controller to use the service as well.

Comment: @Cerad This recommendation  is a good clean approach.

Comment: @Cerad Same error occurs. I instantiate the service like this: `$invoice = $this->getContainer()->get('invoices');` then call the method on that. If it helps, the error is being created at this line in the Controller class: `if (!$this->container->has('doctrine'))`

Comment: Dependency injection and the service container is one of the more powerful features of Symfony and you are going to need to spend some sime understanding how things work.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html.  Your error message indicates that your service is trying to access the container to get the doctrine manager.  But of course you have not injected the container nor should you.  Instead you should inject the entity manager into your service.  Read through the docs and some tutorials until you understand this.  Otherwise, you won't get very far.

Comment: OK well I have gone through the article step by step, and used their examples to create the service, but after debugging it seems that the following line in Controller.php is ALWAYS returning null: `$this->container->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest()` which means it does not fully perform the function's purpose. I'm not really sure how else I can get my cron job to work - it's normally so simple in general, just point to a file and run it....

Answer (score 2):

I fear you may still not be understanding the big picture.  Console apps don't have a request object and thus the whole request_stack is not going to work.  I know you tried creating a request object but that is not going to impact the request stack.

Your console app should look something like:

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
  $data = [
    'client'  => 14,
    'invoice' => 3,
    'dl'      => 0,
  ];
  $invoiceManager = $this->getContainer()->get('invoices');

  $results = $invoiceManager->generateInvoice($data);
}
```

Your controller action would be something like:

```
public function generateInvoiceAction(Request $request)
{
  $data = [
    'client'  => $request->attribute->get('client'),
    'invoice' => $request->attribute->get('invoice'),
    'dl'      => $request->attribute->get('dl'),
  ];
  $invoiceManager = $this->getContainer()->get('invoices');

  $results = $invoiceManager->generateInvoice($data);
```

The invoice manager might look like:

```
class InvoiceManager {
  public function __construct($em) {
    $em = $this->em;
  }
  public function generateInvoice($data) {
    $client = $this->em->find('Client',$data['client']);
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I understand better now - when you say InvoiceManager is this the model? If i am to understand fully, the console command runs the manager method which gets the data, then runs my COntroller method called generateInvoiceAction? This is the function that implements InvoicePainter and emails it to the client.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, but I have tried implementing this but when I run the command it tells me that the argument passed to generateInvoiceAction should be an instance of Request but it's just passing an array of data. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yep.  Your console app should not be calling the controller at all.  It should be calling the invoice manager service.

Comment: OK cool - I guess the service just lives in the AppBundle as well, but just does not extend the Controller? Am I am able to call the Controller within the service? You'll have to bear with me, I've not really written my own services before, thanks.

Comment: I think that this method, although probably more sensible, will not work for me to be honest. My invoice controller relies on the request stack and I won't be able to write it in my service. I've written a new function in my controller called runCronAction() which gets the relevant data from my database and then runs the generateInvoiceAction() method in that controller. In my cron job I just run the runCronAction() function every morning by using a curl statement to that page.